# UIView subclasses with properties in UITableView cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a table with prototype cells containing my own UIView subclass. The UIView subclass paints a coloured rectangle. The colour is defined by a property pointing to a structure containing the RGB values for the rectangle along with some text that goes into UILabels in the cell.

The coloured rectangles all have the right colours when the table first loads, but while the labels always stay correct, the colours start getting all mixed up when I scroll the tableview. If I touch a cell to select it the rectangle regains its intended colour.

Some code:

```
@implementation EmbColorWell

@synthesize col;

...

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    UIBezierPath *p;
    p=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    if(col)
    {
      [[UIColor colorWithRed:col->R() green:col->G() blue:col->B() alpha:1.0] setFill];
      [p fill];
    }
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [p stroke];
}


@end
```

col is a pointer to C++ structures.

My code for filling the cells is as following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"colourcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    EmbColorWell *colwellview=(EmbColorWell *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    colwellview.col=colors+indexPath.row;

    UILabel *label=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
    label.text=[NSString stringWithCString:colors[indexPath.row].Name() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    return cell;
}
```

I have the feeling this has something to do with cell reuse and there's some magic in UILabel that deals properly with this and that I am not doing. Or am I just missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Why are you using colwellview.col=colors+indexPath.row rather than colwellview.col=colors[indexPath.row]? What do you have in colors? Is colors an array?

Comment: colors is a pointer to an array of C++ structures. col is just a pointer into that array. I could've used colwellview.col=&colors[indexPath.row].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Apparently all that was needed was a

```
[colwellview setNeedsDisplay];
```

after I set the property in cellForRowAtIndexpath. Simple really. It would probably be even cleaner to incorporate this into a setter method in the EmbColorWell class itself.